# Route to different components when angular app starts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an angular app. 
When a user logs in, I want to display different UI based on user's role. 
A user can be just a **customer** or an **admin**

In my routing module I have the following

```
        {path: '', redirectTo: 'admin-portal' , pathMatch: 'full'},
        {path: 'admin-portal', component: AdminPortalComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
        {path: 'customer-portal', component: CustomerPortalComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
```

I want to be able to fetch a variable from local storage and use it to decide where I redirect the user when the app loads. I am thinking of having a condition like  `{path: '', redirectTo: 1===1 ? 'admin-portal' : 'customer-portal' , pathMatch: 'full'}`

Comment: You're looking for a `Route Guard`, which performs a check and is made to be tied into the router cycle

Comment: @Z.Bagley do you have a quick example?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create another guard and put the conditions inside

```
    @Injectable()
    export class LoadGuard implements CanActivate {
      constructor(private router: Router) {

      }

      canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                  state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        if(1===1){
           this.router.navigate(['admin-portal']);
           return false;
         }else{
           this.router.navigate(['customer-portal']);
           return false;
        }

      }
    }
```

and then in the route

```
{path: '', pathMatch: 'full',component: sampleComponent, canActivate: [LoadGuard]}
```

Comment: I have used your solution but am getting this error: "Error: Invalid configuration of route ''. One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren" .

Comment: I updated the answer by giving the component. but in this case, it won't load this component since we load different component in the LoadGuard.. but we should give one component as angular expects it in the route path.